# Price amount not showing in Stripe Payments modal or RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am trying to incorporate stripe payments into my pin model of my RoR application but to no avail.  Basically, the price does not show (<%= pin.price %> in index.html.erb) and the same price amount does not appear in the stripe payments modal when selected to enter test credentials for payment processing (amount: '<%= @pin.price %>').

When I create a new pin and include pictures, description, etc. and price -- the resulting pin displays all inputed information except for the price. This is where For some reason it is not registering this info into the price column.  When I run rails console the price: is "nil" despite entering one in for it.  I am not sure as to why.  Thus, it just appears blank in both of these areas after creating a new pin and inputting a price value.

I have added a new migration to pins called price with the following in the command line:

```
rails generate migration AddPriceToPins price:decimal
```

Here's what app/db/migrate looks like afterwards:

```
class AddPriceToPins < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
    add_column :pins, :price, :decimal
   end
end
```

Next, I ran "rake db:migrate" successfully.

app/views/pins/

```
<p>
   <strong>Manufacturer:</strong>
   <%= @pin.manufacturer %>
</p>

<% if @pin.is_multi? %>
  <p>
    <strong>Quantity:</strong>
    <%= @pin.quantity %>
 </p>
 <% end %>
 <p>
      <aside id="details-aside" class="col-sm-4">
        <!-- <a id="btn-buy" href="receipt.html" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><b>I want this!</b></a> -->                 

      <% if @pin.user = current_user %>

          <%= form_tag charges_path, id: 'chargesForm' do %>
              <script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeToken' %>
              <%= hidden_field_tag 'stripeEmail' %>  
              <button id="btn-buy" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>   I want this!</button>

              <script>
                  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
                    key: '<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>',
                    token: function(token, arg) {
                      document.getElementById("stripeToken").value = token.id;
                      document.getElementById("stripeEmail").value = token.email;
                      document.getElementById("chargesForm").submit();
                    }
                  });
                   document.getElementById('btn-buy').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
                    handler.open({
                      name: 'OMG! <%= @pin.manufacturer %>',
                      description: '<%= @pin.description %>',
                      amount: '<%= @pin.price %>'
                  });
                  e.preventDefault();
                 })
              </script>
          <% end %>

      <% else %>

          <%= link_to 'I want this!', new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" %>

      <% end %>
```

app/views/pins/index.html.erb

```
 <%= render 'pages/home' unless user_signed_in? %>

 <h3>Listings</h3>
   <% if user_signed_in? %>
     <%= link_to '+Add Listing', new_pin_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
     <% else %>
     <%= link_to '+Add Listing', new_user_session_path, class: "btn btn-default" %>
   <% end %>
  <%= link_to 'Buy Request', contact_path, class: "btn btn-danger" %>

  <div id="pins" class="transitions-enabled">
     <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
      <div class="box panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= link_to (image_tag pin.image.url(:medium)), pin %>
          <p></p>
          <strong>Manufacturer:</strong>
          <%= pin.manufacturer %>
          <p></p>
          <strong>Price:</strong>
          <%= pin.price %>
          <p></p>
          <strong>Description:</strong>
          <%= pin.description %>
          <% if pin.is_multi? %>
            <strong>Quantity:</strong>
              <%= pin.quantity %>
              <% end %>
             <p></p>
```

Not sure what's causing the issue. Any suggestions for how to patch this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: I don't know about the rest of your code... but this must surely be a bug: `<% if @pin.user = current_user %>` - did you mean `==` here?

Comment: Also instead of `(image_tag pin.image.url(:medium))` you should probably just use: `image_tag(pin.image.url(:medium))`

Comment: As to your actual problem... you haven't shown us any code that is actually stripe-related... how do you know the stripe transaction is getting successfully created? How do you know that price should have a value at this point in time? can you confirm that the `pin` that you're looking at has a price in `rails console` ?

Comment: After running rails console Pin.find(#) on several pins it returns "price: nil"  -- what other information can I supply that would be helpful here?  Thank you and good catch with the first bug!

Comment: well... if there aren't any prices, then they won't show up on the view... :) I think you need to explain more why you're expecting there to be a price when there isn't anything in that column yet :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I create a new pin and include pictures, description, etc. and price -- the resulting pin displays all inputed information except for the price.  This is where I am lost. For some reason it is not registering this info into the price column.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: aha, so probably the issue is with the inputting, rather than the outputting... and at a wild guess, first thing I'd do is double-check you've added price to your permit/require params.

Comment: Yes!  This totally worked!  Thank you Taryn!  All I didn't include :price in my params for pin.  Feel free to write this up and I'll go ahead and accept you're answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hokay, to the end result, after some back and forth, was that the issue was occurring during inputting of the price, rather than an error in output... and that led me to think of adding the price column to the permit./require section of the controller.